# try to install python-pycompile in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

```
most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 209, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 150, in compile
    raise py_exc
__main__.PyCompileError: Sorry: IndentationError: expected an indented block (loginProblemsAndCauses.py, line 156)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 218, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 213, in main
    if quiet < 2:
NameError: name 'quiet' is not defined
```

Try installing a more recent version of python-pycompile, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.  Thanks!

Can anyone help me with this? I get this being in the python-mode in emacs (better in doom emacs)

Comment: Having the same issue. I'm using spacemacs with pyenv enabled and it should be using python 3.9.6, but I get this error pointing back to what looks like the system python 3.8. I haven't figured out how to get python-mode to use the global pyenv version 3.9.6.

Comment: See the part where it told you "Try installing a more recent version of python-pycompile, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release. Thanks!"? **Did you try that**?